# Simple Text Search Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, sh

I have a text file with 10 k lines. How do I extract all the lines where a certain keyword appears? It's fundamental that I am able to select the entire line where a certain text pattern shows up. How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` to search for text and print matching lines:

```
grep yourKeyword yourFile.txt
```

If the pattern consists of several words, you must quote the pattern:

```
grep "your key string" yourFile.txt
```

Comment: Magic! And then I did: grep "keyword phrase" ALL.csv > found.csv

Comment: @Roger: Indeed; `grep` can do wonderful things (`egrep` can handle regexes too), and I/O redirection is always handy too. :-)

Comment: You mean, if I wish to find a keyword, let's say, in the end of the line, I could use grep with regex?

Comment: @Roger: Correct: `egrep "this is the end\$" file.txt`, or `egrep "^this is the start" file.txt`, or `egrep "^this is the entire line\$" file.txt` (the backslash is to prevent bash from interpreting the dollar sign as the start of a shell variable).

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `grep` you can also use `awk`. Plus, `awk` has the advantage of doing processing as it searches the lines..

```
awk '/pattern/{ do stuff }' file
```